# JTextField get no focus when in a heavy-weight popup

Tags: java, swing, popup

I want do display a text filed in a popup. When popup is completly over the application frame (MediumWeightPopup) - all works fine, but when a part of popup is outside of frame (HeavyWeightPopup) it cannot be focused. In this case caret is invisible and no text input is possible.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PopupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Popup test");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup pop;
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    if (pop != null) {
                        pop.hide();
                    }
                    JPanel popupPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                    popupPanel.add(field);
                    pop = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(p, popupPanel, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                    pop.show();
                    System.out.println("Popup type: " + pop.getClass().getName());
                    System.out.println("Can get focus? " + field.requestFocusInWindow());
                }
            }
        });
        frm.add(p);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

On right click near to right border of window I get a non-focusable text field. The same problem I get with any other component in popup that allows key control (for example JTable).

How can I focus a component in a HeavyWeightPopup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also struggled with this years ago. I can't figure out how to give initial focus to a component on the popup. Here are some of my questions/observations:

> What is the Popup class used for?
>
> I always thought that a Popup should have some basic functionality, such as the pupup should close when:
>
> a) the escape key is pressed
>   b) the popup loses focus
>
> The popup class provides none of the above functionality and in fact seems to require some obscure code to even get the keyboard focus to work properly.
>
> Using a JWindow seems to provide the same functionality as a Popup.
>
> JPopupMenu seems to support both of the above requirements.
>
> Run the following program:
>
> a) click on each of the buttons
>   b) click on an empty part of the frame

It appears to me that whenever you need a "popup" you should use a `JPopupMenu`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class PopupTest extends JFrame
{
    String[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

    public PopupTest()
    {
        getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        JButton popup = new JButton("Popup as Popup");
        popup.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                popupPopup(e);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(popup);
        JButton window = new JButton("Window as Popup");
        window.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                windowPopup(e);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(window);

        JButton menu = new JButton("PopupMenu as Popup");
        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                menuPopup(e);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(menu);
    }

    private void popupPopup(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JList list = new JList(numbers);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);

        PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
        Popup popup = factory.getPopup(this, list, getLocation().x, getLocation().y+100);
        //popup.show();

        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(list);

        if (window != null)
        {
            window.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        }

        popup.show();
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent(list);
    }

    private void windowPopup(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JList list = new JList(numbers);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JWindow window = new JWindow(this);
        window.getContentPane().add(list);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocation(getLocation().x + 200, getLocation().y+100);

        window.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("deactivated");
            }
        });
    }

    private void menuPopup(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JList list = new JList(numbers);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add( new JTextField(10) );
        menu.add( list );

        menu.show((Component)e.getSource(), 0, 100);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new PopupTest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Edit:

Based on Sergiy's answer, this code was close to working. The difference in the `popupPopup()` method is that the `show()` method needs to be invoked AFTER the window is made focusable. Code updated to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks for the solution (and upvote from me + mark as accepted). Probably I'll use it somewhere else. But I've found another one, which is better in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Source code analyse brought me another solution

```
pop = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(p, popupPanel, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
// some new stuff
Window win = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(popupPanel);
if (win instanceof JWindow && win.getType() == Window.Type.POPUP) {
    win.setFocusableWindowState(true);
}
// continue old stuff
pop.show();
```

So the complete example looks like

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PopupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Popup test");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup pop;
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    if (pop != null) {
                        pop.hide();
                    }
                    JPanel popupPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                    popupPanel.add(field);
                    pop = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(p, popupPanel, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                    Window win = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(popupPanel);
                    if (win instanceof JWindow && win.getType() == Window.Type.POPUP) {
                        win.setFocusableWindowState(true);
                    }
                    pop.show();
                    System.out.println("Popup type: " + pop.getClass().getName());
                    System.out.println("Can get focus? " + field.requestFocusInWindow());
                }
            }
        });
        frm.add(p);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Interesting**: the call `field.requestFocusInWindow()` still returns false, but field gets focus anyway.

**BTW**: this solution is also better for me because in my real code I get the Popup from a `JComboBox` (my goal is to create `JTableComboBox` with a table in popup and an optional filter field on top of the table).

Comment: Can you explain why Window.setFocusableWindowState(true) solves the problem? If I call getFocusableWindowState before setting it to true, it returns also true. Don't get it why...