# Swing popup flickers when resized to the left

Tags: macos, swing, popup

What I would like to achieve is having a popup showing on the right of the frame:

[image]
[image]

The goal of this popup is to mimic a `ComboBox` dropdown menu, but in more flexible way. E.g. it can expand additional content.
Also I'm trying to make the popup remains within the bounds of the main `JFrame`, since the trigger component is located on the right of the `JFrame`, the popup has to expand on its left.

I have a piece of code that behaves as intended, that is : the popup is expanded (shows a `JPanel` that was not visible before) on the left or shrunk (the additional panel is set to non-visible).

However I noticed the popup **flickers** when it is relocated (expanded or shrinked).

Goin frame by frame on a screen recording reveals what happens when the popup flickers:

> The screenshot below comes from the *screen recording* opened in QuickTime, the scree capture is cropped to focus on the popup, clearly the parent JFrame is not resized.

- After clicking on "More" button (**expand**): the popup size and location were updated but the content happened is being repainted too early

  [image: expand paint too early]
- After clicking on "Less" button (**shrink**): the location is updated, but the size and content are out of date.

  [image: shrink is out of date]

The feature is implemented that way, the popup is create at the bottom right of the button using the coordinate computed by `locationAtBottomRight` :

```java
var popupLocation = locationAtBottomRight(dropdownButton, popupContent);
popup.ref = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(
        dropdownButton,
        popupContent,
        popupLocation.x,
        popupLocation.y
);
popup.ref.show();
```

When the more button in the popup is clicked, it sets visible a panel and updates the parent panel size

```java
moreButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
    secondary.setVisible(!secondary.isVisible());
    moreButton.setText(secondary.isVisible() ? "Less..." : "More...");
    var newSize = new Dimension(main.getPreferredSize());
    if (secondary.isVisible()) {
        newSize.width += secondary.getPreferredSize().width;
    }
    popupContent.setSize(newSize);
});
```

When this happens the component listener on `popupContent` gets invoked and updates the popup size and location.

```java
popupContent.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        resizeAndRelocatePopup(dropdownButton, popupContent);
        System.out.println("componentResized: " +popupContent.getPreferredSize());
    }
});
```

Setting the location `Window::setLocation` and the size `Window::setSize` of the popup is invoked on the `Window` of the popup.

```java
private static void resizeAndRelocatePopup(JComponent owner, JComponent popupContent) {
    var popupWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupContent);
    var newPopupLocation = locationAtBottomRight(owner, popupContent);
    popupWindow.setLocation(newPopupLocation);
    popupWindow.setSize(popupContent.getPreferredSize());
    // failed attempt to avoid the popup getting painted too early
    popupWindow.revalidate();
}
```

I believe this is this last piece of code that is the cause of the flickers. I have tried using usual tricks like `revalidate` / `repaint`, but this didn't help.

---

Here's the whole code to reproduce the issue. Example ran with JDK 21, but should work on JDK 11 as well.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PopupStuffJ {
    /**
     * Resize and relocate the popup window, according to the preferred size of the popup content.
     */
    private static void resizeAndRelocatePopup(JComponent owner, JComponent popupContent) {
        var popupWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupContent);
        var newPopupLocation = locationAtBottomRight(owner, popupContent);
        popupWindow.setLocation(newPopupLocation);
        popupWindow.setSize(popupContent.getPreferredSize());

        // failed attempt to avoid the popup getting painted too early
        popupWindow.revalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Compute location at bottom right of owner component, using the preferred width of the popup content.
     */
    private static Point locationAtBottomRight(JComponent owner, JComponent popupContent) {
        var popupLocation = owner.getLocationOnScreen();
        popupLocation.x = popupLocation.x + owner.getWidth() - popupContent.getPreferredSize().width;
        popupLocation.y += owner.getHeight();
        return popupLocation;
    }

    private static JButton buttonWithDropDown() {
        var popup = new Object() {
            Popup ref = null;
        };

        // This button is merely here to trigger the popup
        // In actual code, this triggered by a third party component
        var dropdownButton = new JButton("Dropdown Menu");
        dropdownButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
            if (popup.ref != null) {
                popup.ref.hide();
                popup.ref = null;
                return;
            }

            // Computes the location of the popup according to the button and the popup content
            var popupContent = popupContent();

            // This code that relocates and resizes the popup
            popupContent.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    resizeAndRelocatePopup(dropdownButton, popupContent);
                    System.out.println("componentResized: " +popupContent.getPreferredSize());
                }
            });

            // When first displayed show popup at the right location
            var popupLocation = locationAtBottomRight(dropdownButton, popupContent);
            popup.ref = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(
                    dropdownButton,
                    popupContent,
                    popupLocation.x,
                    popupLocation.y
            );
            popup.ref.show();
        });
        return dropdownButton;
    }

    private static JComponent popupContent() {
        var secondary = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        secondary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        secondary.setVisible(false);
        secondary.setOpaque(false);
        secondary.add(new JTextArea("Expanded"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        var main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        var textArea = new JTextArea("Click more to expand on the left");
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        main.add(textArea);

        var moreButton = new JButton("More...");
        main.add(moreButton);
        main.setOpaque(false);

        var popupContent = new JPanel();
        popupContent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(popupContent, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        popupContent.add(secondary);
        popupContent.add(main);

        // update the size of the popupContent panel,
        // to either expand or shrink the popup
        // when button More... is clicked
        moreButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
            secondary.setVisible(!secondary.isVisible());
            moreButton.setText(secondary.isVisible() ? "Less..." : "More...");

            var newSize = new Dimension(main.getPreferredSize());
            if (secondary.isVisible()) {
                newSize.width += secondary.getPreferredSize().width;
            }
            popupContent.setSize(newSize);
        });
        return popupContent;
    }

    private static JComponent frameContent() {
        var toolbar = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        toolbar.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        toolbar.add(new JLabel("xxxx"));
        toolbar.add(buttonWithDropDown());
        toolbar.setOpaque(false);

        var frameContent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frameContent.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frameContent.setOpaque(false);
        return frameContent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            var jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            var contentPane = jFrame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.setBackground(new Color(0xFFC499));
            contentPane.add(frameContent());
            jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @camickr FYI I just changed the reproducer to Java.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. The images show a frame with a popup. When I click on the button the frame size changes? Why would the size change if you want a popup? With a popup you are adding a "popup" on top of the frame, so the layout of the frame doesn't change. Code seems overly complex. Don't know if it will help but here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586219/131872) here is some code with different options for displaying a popup on top of a frame.

Comment: I wanted is to mimic a combobox drop-down popup, and expand it (on the left as I don't want to go outside the frame since the location is on right side), the additional panel should have other controls. Also thank you  for the link it's interesting, but does not cover why I;m trying to achieve.

Comment: *but does not cover why I;m trying to achieve.* - It is a better starting point than what you posted here. It shows how to display a popup when you click a button, which is basically what you are trying to achieve. You just need to modify the code to set the location of the popup. As I stated in my first comment, I have no idea why the size of your main frame changes just because you are showing a popup. Maybe I don't understand your problem and the [mre] is not very clear.

Comment: _I have no idea why the size of your main frame changes just because you are showing a popup_, non no I try to change the size of the popup window not the main frame. _You just need to modify the code to set the location of the popup_ but the code is already doing that : `w.setLocation(newPopupLocation)` _which is basically what you are trying to achieve_, not exactly I want to adjust the location and size of the popup when a button in the popup is clicked. Thank you a lot for the feedback, I'll rework my description and code as I understand it's not very clear.

Comment: 1) *I try to change the size of the popup window not the main frame.* - the problem is that the code is changing the main frame, not the popup. 2) *I want to adjust the location and size of the popup when a button in the popup is clicked* - which is the "second" phase of the requirement. First you need to display the popup correctly when a button on the frame is clicked. 3) New code still doesn't even to step 1 correctly. That is why I suggest you start with my working examples.

Comment: _the problem is that the code is changing the main frame, not the popup_ Maybe I've looked too much at my code, but where is the code touching the _main frame_ ?
During debug I only saw the window of the popup.
Also I have looked at the linked answer as you suggested but how does that help me reshape an _already displayed_ popup window?
Sorry if I sound repeating, but I'm not a Swing expert, and I'd like to precisely understand what is wrong here.

Comment: I would consider making use of the `JRootPane`'s `glassPane` - see [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer GlassPanes are great unfortunately in the real code (IntelliJ IDEA) I cannot use that. Also on macOs I think it would lack the "standard" drop shadow.

I'm starting to think of this issue there as a limitation if not a bug of the macOs impl of _Popup_ in general as _camickr_ pointed out the javadoc says they should be recreated when reshaped.

Answer (score 1):

> but where is the code touching the main frame ?

I don't know.

However, when I run your code and click on the "Dropdown Menu" button the frame gets resized smaller. This is what I see:

[image]

When I resize the frame I then see this:

[image]

Why does the frame go smaller. I don't know. It would appear you have a setSize() method that works on the frame NOT the popup. You can't solve the resizing/reshaping issue until this initial problem is solved. Note in the 3 examples I provided, the size of the frame does not change. That is why I suggested you start with working code. I can't even begin to help with the More/Less logic until the popup is initially displayed correctly.

> I have looked at the linked answer

The answer shows 3 different approaches to showing a popup. One of them uses a JWindow. You could also use an undecorated JDialog.

> but how does that help me reshape an already displayed popup window?

The above approach will allow you to create your popup component just like any other JFrame. Then you can resize/reshape the window as required.

To me all you need is ActionListeners. On the "Dropdown Menu" button the ActionListener would create and show the popup window. On the popup window you might have two buttons "More..." and "Less...". Only one would be visible at a time depending on the current state of the window. Then you add an ActionListener to each button. The "More..." listener would resize the window by adding more content to the window and then resetting the location based on the size of the newly added content. The "Less..." listener would remove the content and reset the size/location.

Also I see "Mo..." on the button which indicates a problem. Your code has too many setPreferredSize(...) statement. There should be no need for any of them. Just create the components and add them to the window. Each component will determine its own preferred size.

Here is a basic example to get you started that uses most of the suggestions from above:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class PopupStuff extends JPanel
{
    public PopupStuff()
    {
        JButton dropdown = new JButton("Dropdown Menu");
        add(dropdown);
        dropdown.addActionListener((e) -> dropdown(e));
    }

    private void dropdown(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
        Point buttonLocation = button.getLocationOnScreen();

        JDialog dialog = new PopupDialog();
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        // modify the logic here to position the popup at the left edge of the button.

        dialog.setLocation(buttonLocation.x, buttonLocation.y + 50);

        dialog.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
            {
                Window window = (Window)e.getSource();
                window.dispose();
            }
        });

    }

    class PopupDialog extends JDialog
    {
        private JTextArea expandedContent;
        private JButton more;
        private JButton less;

        public PopupDialog()
        {
            setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            expandedContent = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            expandedContent.setVisible( false );
            add(expandedContent, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Some component bigger than the button"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            more = new JButton("More...");
            buttonsPanel.add(more);
            more.addActionListener((e) -> adjustFrameLocation(true));

            less = new JButton("Less...");
            less.setVisible( false );
            buttonsPanel.add(less);
            less.addActionListener((e) -> adjustFrameLocation(false));

            pack();
        }

        private void adjustFrameLocation(boolean isExpanding)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();

            expandedContent.setVisible( isExpanding );
            more.setVisible( !isExpanding );
            less.setVisible( isExpanding );

            pack();

            int locationX = bounds.x - getSize().width + bounds.width;
            setLocation(locationX, bounds.y);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new PopupStuff() );
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

The main point of the code is to isolate the "popup" from the main frame.

> Edit

I found a comment in the Popup API that states:

***The general contract is that if you need to change the size of the Component, or location of the Popup, you should obtain a new Popup.***

I modified the code as below and the frame no longer shrinks and the Popup is displayed at the right edge of the dropdown button.

When I click "More..." the Popup also expands correctly to the left.

However, when I click "Less..." a new Popup is displayed in the smaller size but the original popup is still visible in the expanded size.

So I think the solution is to create a class/instance variable for the Popup. Then at the start of the method you would "hide" the previous Popup before displaying the new Popup.

Because the MRE uses all static methods, I didn't attempt to implement this solution. I hope your real code doesn't use static methods since that is a poor design.

```
private static void resizeAndRelocatePopup(JComponent owner, JComponent popupContent) {
    //var popupWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupContent);
    //var popupWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner);
    var newPopupLocation = locationAtBottomRight(owner, popupContent);
    //popupWindow.setLocation(newPopupLocation);
    //popupWindow.setSize(popupContent.getPreferredSize());

    // failed attempt to avoid the popup getting painted too early
    //popupWindow.revalidate();

    Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(
                owner,
                popupContent,
                newPopupLocation.x,
                newPopupLocation.y
        );
        popup.show();
}
```

Comment: _click on the "Dropdown Menu" button the frame gets resized smaller_ That is strange! On macOS I don't see this behavior. _You could also use an undecorated JDialog_ Unfortunately I cannot use another approach there, as the type of popup is determined by third party (or framework) code. And by inspecting their code I was able to reproduce exactly the same problem with the popup. Debugging the repaint manager I saw that on reshape, macOs implementation first moves then resize the popup, and later the **previous** "rendered content" got shifted to the new place, then Swing paints the new content

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with macOs implementation, the code provided above with the `JDialog`, if I set `setUndecorated(true);` in the `PopupDialog` constructor and run this, I see the [same kind of flickering](https://imgur.com/a/Ia5NUL7).

Comment: One of the actual purpose is to have that (among other cases, e.g. making the popup have a calendar, that can show previous month, or showing a color chooser) : https://imgur.com/a/pqfQ9aW

Comment: About the app `JFrame` resizing, **on OSX** `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupContent);` returns the native window **of the popup**, could it be that **on Windows** this returns the native window of the App ?

Comment: That could definitely be the difference. You should not assume a Window is the parent container for the popupContent. I've always thought that a popup was just a component displayed on the "popup layer" of the layered pane used by the frame. See my edit for a different implementation of the resizeAndRelocatePopup(). method.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting ! I'll try that. One case I think might need consideration though is handling focus, i.e in one of the use case, a list element is _hovered_ because the mouse was over this element. Closing then opening a new popup is likely requiring to simulate a mouse event.
Also the real code is indeed using an instance field the popup.

Comment: This suggested approach that recreate a new popup avoids the "displacement" flicker, it's promising in that regard. It's way more stable, however there's still some flicker on shrink, the popup window appear first blank without content and it refreshes with the components updated. Hiding the previous popup after showing the new, but it's not enough.

Comment: *the popup window appear first blank without content* - that might make sense since a component can only have a single parent so it need to be removed from the previous popup before it can be added to the new popup. Maybe try wrapping the showing of the new Popup in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). to make sure the original Popup is hidden. Refresh question with update MRE. Also note this is why I suggested using an undecorated JDialog instead of a Popup. To me the dialog just becomes a wrapper container for whatever child component you want to display.